# My fullscreen background doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want my header to be a full screen background.
Code works on other sites that i previously made but now it doesn't work.
Please help.

The code is same on other websites. And it works.

Here is my html5 and css3:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: roboto;
}

header {
  background: url('./pics/bg1.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome | SoundNet</title>
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#6699ff">
  <!--Meta-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,  user-capable=yes">
  <!--Js-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <!--Link-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Playlists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <span class="border-n">N</span>ESTA
      <div class="button">
        Sign Up
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="party">
      <h3>Get the party started</h3>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

[Edit: Added snippet but no image, for the moment.]

Comment: add `html, body { width: 100%;height: 100% }`

Comment: to explain Red's comment: % in CSS works only if parent hierarchy is defined in % too, up to `html` and `body`

Comment: @Red thanks it work's now

Comment: @Kaddath i'll keep that on my mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `height` for the body. 100% height and width takes its parent height and width.

Because your body dont have both a width and height, the 100% height and width of your header won't have any effect.

**Snippet**

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  background: url('https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```